# Runtime error '13': Type Mismatch, In accessing value from Dictionary

Tags: vba, excel

I have created a dictionary for key Value pair list. In which key should be string and Value part should be arrayList. When I am adding the key and Value in Dictionary it is working fine but when I am trying to get the value as arrayList it is giving Runtime Error '13'

```
   Dim myValue As Dictionary
   Dim inrArrLstVal As Object
   Dim arrLstStor as Object

   Set myValue = New Dictionary
   Set arrLstStor = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
   Set inrArrLstVal = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

   myValue.Add searchpart, inrArrLstVal   ''' searchpart is string
   arrLstStor = myValue .Items(searchpart) ''' This gives type Mismatch Error '13'.
```

Can anyone tell me why it is giving such an error and how can I get value.

Comment: I don't understand what are you trying to say. I have used Set.

Comment: Gary's saying to use Set when you return the value to `arrLsrStor`. Can you try it snd check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Sub testarrlst()

    Dim dc As Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim inrArrLstVal As Object
    Dim arrLstStor As Object

    Set dc = New Scripting.Dictionary
    Set inrArrLstVal = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

    dc.Add "test", inrArrLstVal
    Set arrLstStor = dc.Item("test")

    Debug.Print TypeName(arrLstStor)

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @Dick Kusleika for such an Answer. Here in the last line, instead of using 'TypeName(arrLstStor)', I used 'arrLstStor(1)'. This is giving me the result what I am wanting.